# Is a locally invertible weak limit of injective maps injective almost everywhere?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, sobolev-spaces, geometric-measure-theory, calculus-of-variations

This is a [cross-post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3873192/is-a-locally-invertible-weak-limit-of-injective-maps-injective-almost-everywhere).

Let $\Omega_1,\Omega_2 \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ be open, connected, bounded, with non-empty $C^1$ boundaries.

Let $f_n:\bar\Omega_1 \to \bar\Omega_2$ be Lipschitz **injective** maps with $\det(df_n)>0$, and suppose that $f_n$ converges to a $C^1$ function $f: \bar\Omega_1 \to \bar\Omega_2$ **weakly** in $W^{1,2}$, and that $\det(df)>0$ everywhere on $\bar\Omega_1$.

> Is it true that $|f^{-1}(y)| \le 1$ a.e. on $\Omega_2$?

Does the answer change if we assume in addition that $f_n|_{K} \to f|_{K}$ **strongly** in $W^{1,2}$ for every $K \subset \subset \Omega_1$?

---

The condition $\det(df)>0$ rules out degenerate counterexamples such as $f_n(x)=\frac{x}{n}$ which converge to a constant.

Comment: What does it mean "Lipschitz injective"?

Comment: I just mean that each $f_n$ is a Lipschitz map (with a Lipschitz constant which might depend on $n$) and that it's injective on $\Omega_1$. I am fine with replacing the injectivity assumption with the requirement $|f_n^{-1}(y)| \le 1$ for almost every $y \in \Omega_2$. And of course by $\det(df_n)>0$ I mean "almost everywhere", since $df$ might not be defined on all  $\Omega_1$.

Comment: I am pretty sure that what you ask is true as it is essentially just degree theory for Sobolev spaces in conjunction with the fact that non-negative determinants converge slightly better than one would expect. You don't even need to exclude the degenerate case of constants, as for those $|f^{-1}(y)|=0$ a.e. anyway. I'll try to give a full answer once I find the time.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds interesting. I know that the Jacobians $Jf_n$ converge weakly in $L^1(K)$ for $K \subset \subset \Omega_1$; Unfortunately, I am not sufficiently familiar with degree theory in the Sobolev context; it sounds like the right tool tough. I would be happy to see the details.

Comment: @LeoMoos Thanks, but I am not sure how do you continue from here. Also is it clear that $\int Jf$ is an integer multiple of the image's volume? (We have manifolds with boundary here; does that covering argument requires assuming that $f(\partial \Omega_1) \subseteq \partial \Omega_2$?)

Comment: Along the same lines as suggested above, from the weak $W^{1,2}$-convergence one finds that $Q \mathcal{H}^2(\mathrm{im} \, f) \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \mathcal{H}^2(\mathrm{im} \, f_n)$, where $f$ covers its image $Q \in \mathbf{Z}_{>0}$ times. One other hand, it seems to me that the strong $L^2$-convergence shows that $\mathrm{im} \, f_n \to \mathrm{im} \, f$ with respect to Hausdorff distance, and therefore $\mathcal{H}^2(\mathrm{im} \, f) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathcal{H}^2(\mathrm{im} \, f_n)$.

Comment: @Asaf Sorry, I kept rewriting my comment in the hopes of making it more succinct. I don't think the argument requires thinking about the boundaries, but rather showing that the number of pre-images is constant equals $Q$. Have you tried something along the following lines: by the inverse function theorem, for all $y \in \mathrm{im}\, f$ there is a radius $\rho > 0$ so that the points in $B_\rho(y)$ have the same number of preimages; in other words it's locally constant. As the image of $f$ is connected, it must be constant globally.

Comment: @LeoMoos I don't think strong $L^2$ alone gives you Hausdorff-convergence of the image. But you can get uniform convergence on an arbitrary large subset which gives you Hausdorff convergence of that image and then try to argue that the image of the leftover set is small via the weak $L^1$-convergence of the determinant.

Comment: @mlk You're of course correct, I went a bit too quickly there. The argument I was thinking of only gives only direction I believe. The correction you suggest seems sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, let me try a writeup of the comment chain. For any reasonable subset $A\subset \Omega_2$ and $B := f^{-1}(A)$ you get
$$\int_A |f^{-1}(y)| dy = \int_B \det df dx \leq \liminf_{n\to\infty} \int_B \det df_n dx = \liminf_{n\to\infty} \mathcal{H}^2(f_n(B)). $$

Then if we know that $\mathcal{H}^2(f_n(B)) \to \mathcal{H}^2(f(B)) \leq \mathcal{H}^2(A)$ ($A$ can have points with no preimage), we get that $|f^{-1}(y)| \leq 1$ a.e. as $A$ was arbitrary.

Now using the existence of a pointwise a.e. converging subsequence (never relabeled) and Egorov's theorem, for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is $B_\epsilon$ such that $\mathcal{H}^2(B \setminus B_\epsilon) < \epsilon$ and $f_n$ converges uniformly on $B_\epsilon$. But then a quick argument shows that $f_n(B_\epsilon)$ converges in the Hausdorff-sense and thus $\mathcal{H}^2(f_n(B_\epsilon)) \to \mathcal{H}^2(f(B_\epsilon))$. Now the leftover set is small and Müller's famous result gives us that $\det df_n$ converges weakly in $L^1$ (see ¹). So in particular as $\chi_{B\setminus B_\epsilon} \in (L^1)^*$
$$\mathcal{H}^2(f_n(B\setminus B_\epsilon)) = \int_{B\setminus B_\epsilon} \det d f_n dy \to \int_{B\setminus B_\epsilon} \det df dy $$
which is small for small enough $\epsilon$ as $f \in C^1$. Similarly
$$\mathcal{H}^2(f(B\setminus B_\epsilon)) \leq \int_{B\setminus B_\epsilon} \det df dy.$$

¹As remarked by Asaf in the comments, the result gives convergence on compact subsets. However as $\Omega_1$ is $C^1$, there exists an extension operator to a larger domain $\Omega \supset \Omega_1$ and thus $\tilde{f}_n,\tilde{f} \in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ such that $\tilde{f}_n \to \tilde{f}$ in the same sense and $\tilde{f}_n|_{\Omega_1} = f_n, \tilde{f}|_{\Omega_1} = f$. Now $\overline{\Omega_1} \subset \Omega$ is the required compact set.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a nice solution! I have one question: Müller's result gives weak convergene of the Jacobians on $L^1(K)$ for compactly contained subsets $K \subset \subset \Omega_1$. So, for your argument to work you need to make sure that $B=f^{-1}(A)$ is compactly contained in the interior $\Omega_1$.  (I actually think that you need it also for the first $\liminf$ inequality $\int_B \det df dx \leq \liminf_{n\to\infty} \int_B \det df_n dx $.)

Comment: I don't think that it's trivial to guarantee this, since even though $f \in C^1$, we don't know that it's injective (yet), so $A$ may well have some weird pre-images which are close to the boundary of $\Omega_1$

Comment: @AsafShachar Ah, yeah I forgot that detail. However the fix is easy. Since $\Omega_1$ has $C^1$ boundary there is an extension operator for $W^{1,2}$. So we can extend $f_n$ to $\Omega \supset \Omega_1$ with the same convergence and then $\overline{\Omega_1}$ is compact within $\Omega$.